# Error compiling Boost.Asio example code

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to get to grips with boost asio using the provided daytime examples [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html). But when I try to compile it, I get this error:

```
‘boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor’ has no member named ‘io_service’
```

Here's the relevant code section:

```
 void start_accept()
  {
    tcp_connection::pointer new_connection =
      tcp_connection::create(acceptor_.io_service());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the linked source code the line goes like this:

```
tcp_connection::create(acceptor_.get_io_service());
```

You should revert that change you made to your copy.

Comment: Worked on Boost 1.58.0 and Ubuntu 16.04